# Display form data selected using Laravel / Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following script which display all the cities of a country.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
       
       $("#pays").change(function(){

          /* let country_id = this.value;*/
          let country_id = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");


           $.get('/getState/'+country_id,function(data){

              $("#ville").html(data);

           });
       });

  });

</script>
```

And the following view :

```
<div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <label>Pays</label>
                           <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="pays" id="pays">
                             <option label="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
                             @foreach($countries as $country)
                           <option data-id="{{$country->id}}" value="{{$country->name}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                           </select>
                       </div>  
                       <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <label>Ville</label>
                           <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="ville" id="ville">
                            
                           </select>
                       </div>
                  </div>
```

I'm trying to update data , so to do that I should display data in the form , So I'm using the following script :

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
           console.log(id);
           $('#form_result').html('');
            $.ajax({
          
           url:"castingss/"+id+"/edit",
           dataType:"json",
           type:"GET",
           success:function(html){
           console.log(html);
           

             $('#pays').val(html.data.pays);
             $('#pays').trigger('change'); 
             $('#ville').val(html.data.ville);
             $('#ville').trigger('change'); 
            
            $('#hidden_id').val(html.data.id);
            $('.modal-title').text("Modifier les informations d'un casting/influenceur");
            $('#action_button').val("Modifier");
            $('#action').val("Modifier");
            $('#formModal').modal('show');
           }
          })
         });
```

But I get the following result :

[image]

I can't display the `ville value` on the form.

What is wrong with my code ?

If you have any idea please help.

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell when we don't know the datas. I mean, a working fiddle or something would be better with your concept. The "html.data.ville" returns the correct value? Have you tried the following? `$("#ville").val(html.data.ville).change();` And finally, I wouldn't recommend to use "html" as param name. Use something like more independent (like result).

Comment: @NagySzabolcs thank you for your comment , I tried what did u say but doesn't work

Comment: What is the value of "html.data.ville"? (change it to result e.g. to be sure).

Comment: the value of "html.data.ville is Manu'a

Comment: Could it be because there is no script with the event changed to ville?

Comment: Can u provide us a single reproductive code? Like in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Make a basic variation of your code with some datas that you get from ajax and we'll be able to help you faster.

Comment: okey , I will do it

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem capital name show based on country selection. I solved this issue like below

```
$("#ville").append("<option value='"+html.data.ville+"'>"+html.data.ville+"</option>");
```

Use below this code before `ajax` request

```
$('#ville').empty();
```